# Removing link from second span

Tags: php

I have a page which list comments of  users.

My problem is that I have two span

[image]

[image]

When i click "devam" link as you see, the second span, the long one is showing.What i want to the is that removing "devamı" button, if the user clicks it.

This is my code.What might be the changes?

```
 {foreach value=users from=$comment}
    <tr>    
        <td>{$users.ADD_DATE}</td>
        <td>{$users.NAME}</td>
        {if $users.COMMENT|count_characters > 95}
        <td width="340px"><span id=comment12kisa_{$users.ID}>{$users.COMMENT|truncate:95:"..."}
            </span><a href=""  onclick="$('#comment12kisa_{$users.ID}').html($('#comment12kisaa_{$users.ID}').html());return false;">devamÄ±</a></td>
        <td><center><input type="checkbox" name="checkComment[]" value={$users.Movie_Comment_ID}-{$users.MOVIE_ID} ></center></td>

            {else}
            <td width="180px">{$users.COMMENT}</td>
            <td><center><input type="checkbox" name="checkComment[]" value={$users.Movie_Comment_ID}-{$users.MOVIE_ID}></center></td>
            {/if}

            <span id="comment12kisaa_{$users.ID}" style="display:none">{$users.COMMENT}</span>

</tr>
        {/foreach}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `$(this).remove();` to the onclick event handler of that link:

```
<a href="" onclick="$('#comment12kisa_{$users.ID}').html($('#comment12kisaa_{$users.ID}').html()); $(this).remove(); return false;">devamÄ±</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

you want to remove a link when its clicked? this can be done if you also are using jquery also

```
<?php
  print "<script type='text/javascript'>
    $('a').text('devami').click(function(){

        $(this).remove();

    });
   </script>";
?>
```